# Modelling cone-like shape on cube corner

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to make the shape in the images, a cone shaped hump. I've tried a number of methods that haven't given me good results.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

here's the blend file - https://www.mediafire.com/file/i2w8p3lcyvbxdyp/curvy_thing.blend/file

I really had no idea what to title this lol

Comment: The shape is not clear, do you have another point of view?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ok7uDdK - here's some more pictures, its hard to find an angle that perfectly shows the shape. It's basically a cone attached to one corner of a bevelled square.

Comment: Maybe show an animated gif with a rotation around the object?

Answer (score 1):

I created this grid just to place the cursor closer to the curve.
So, placing the cursor by the method of experiments, I found a convenient point. Select all points except the first and last, turn on the cursor as a pivot point.

[image]

then scale arc by 1.5

[image]

Then Mesh -> Transform -> To shpere, or press Alt+Shift+S and press 1

[image]

You can experiment and find your own proportions.

[image]

Comment: I think this might be perfect! Thank you, this is just what I was looking for.